# отрицательные элементы парных столбцов переместить вверх

Tags: c#

Необходимо в двумерном массиве переместить отрицательные элементы парных столбцов вверх, не меняя их порядок следования.

Пытаюсь понять принцип как это можно сделать:

```
 Write("Введите ширину массива: ");
        int N = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        Write("Введите длинну массива: ");
        int M = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        Write("Введите диапазон массива: ");
        Write("\n\tВведите минимальное число: ");
        int A = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        Write("\n\tВведите максимальное число: ");
        int B = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        
        int[,] arr = new int[M, N];
        
        Random a = new Random();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                arr[i,j] = a.Next(A, B);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Write("\t" + arr[i,j]);
            }
            WriteLine();
        }

        int tmp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                tmp = arr[0, i];
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
                {
                    //  if(j < 0)
                    {
                        arr[j, i] = arr[j + 1, i];
                    }
                }
            }
            arr[arr.GetLength(0) - 1, i] = tmp;
        }
        Write("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Write("\t" + arr[i, j]);
            }
            WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Для начала надо понять 1) что такое парный столбец 2) что такое переместить вверх 3) что считается изменением порядка их следования. С отрицательными элементами и двумерным массивом вроде понятно. Есть примеры, тестовая программа? Как вы проверите, что оно работает правильно?

Comment: 1) парный столбец - это когда j = 0, 2, 4 и т.д. 2)Переместить вверх - это переместить в начало массива. 3) получается если я в массиве вижу отрицательный элемент, я беру и перетаскиваю его на место первого положительного элемента, а положительный возвращаю на место того отрицательного элемента. Я вижу следующий отрицательный элемент и переставляю его на место второго положительного, а положительный возвращаю на место следующего отрицательного. Если в массиве идут сначала только отрицательные элементы, а потом только положительные - то код работает.

Comment: урааа, наконец-то я смог вставить код без траблов. Раньше как не делал - было бесполезно, не прокатывало. (ну это та часть, где тот массив)

Comment: Так а всё таки, как это записать???

Comment: int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(1); i++) 
                {
                    int k = 0;
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        if (arr[i,j] < 0)
                        {
                            tmp = arr[0 + k, j];
                            arr[0 + k,j] = arr[i,j];
                            arr[i,j] = tmp;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Походу у меня осинение..)

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) {
  int k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i!=0) {
      if (array[i, j] < 0) {
        tmp = array[k, j];
        array[k, j] = array[i, j];
        array[i, j] = tmp;
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/764571)